# Eigenvalue of Linear differential operator with boundary conditions

Tags: functional-analysis

I am wondering if there is a way to find the eigenvalues for some simple-looking equations without solving the equations explicitly. More specifically, the equation(s) are as following:
\begin{equation}
i\frac{d}{dr} \left[\begin{array}{c}\psi_{1}(r)\\
\psi_{2}(r)\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}{cc} -\lambda(r)& \mu(r)\\
-\mu(r)& \lambda(r)\end{array}\right]= E \left[\begin{array}{c}\psi_{1}(r)\\
\psi_{2}(r)\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}

where $E$ is the eigenvalue, $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are two arbitrary functions satisfying the same boundary condition as for $\psi$:
\begin{equation}
\psi(0)=\psi(R)
\end{equation}
i.e. all the functions are defined on the range $[0, R]$.

If you know any text books dealing with such problems, please also let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot answer, but I would have a look at Coddington-Levinson's book "Theory of Ordinary Differential Equations", chapter "Self-adjoint problems on finite intervals".

Comment: Thanks to you, Giuseppe. The book is quite inspiring.